# can't manipulate JSON obtained through multiple $http.get and $q

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to merge two jsons into one but can't make it work. I manage to retrieve the data I need from both get, but I have troubles manipulating the jsons.

I planned on using two for loops but it doesn't work :

```
$scope.coursesJson = $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/18zi3');
    $scope.reviewsJson = $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/52toz');

    $q.all([$scope.coursesJson, $scope.reviewsJson]).then(function (values){
        $scope.coursesJson = values[0];
        $scope.reviewsJson = values[1];

            for(i = 0;i<$scope.coursesJson.length;i++){
                for(j = 0;j<$scope.reviewsJson.length;j++){
                    if($scope.coursesJson[i].name = $scope.reviewsJson[j].name){
                        $scope.coursesJson[i].reviews.push($scope.reviewsJson[j]);
                    }
                }
            }

            console.log($scope.coursesJson);
        });
```

Using the console, I can visualise the data but $scope.coursesJson.length is undefined and I don't understand why.

Maybe I don't understand $q well ?

EDIT :

Here is an example of the elements you could find in the coursesJson file I get() :

```
[{"code":"123 ","name":"Acteurs","courseContentGrade":null,"courseTeachingGrade":null,"courseAverage":null,"reviews":null},
    {"code":"1234","name":"Advanced Excel","courseContentGrade":null,"courseTeachingGrade":null,"courseAverage":null,"reviews":null}]
```

And an example of the elements you could find in the reviewsJson file I get() :

```
[{"code":"123 ","name":"Acteurs","professor":"Lalala","contentReview":"C'est très réussi.","teachingReview":"charismatique","contentGrade":8,"teachingGrade":8,"average":8,"trimester":"T2","day":"Jeudi / Thursday","time":"9h-12h","round":"1er tour","bet":21,"year":"2014/2015","upvotes":"0","author":"Piranha","passed":null},
    {"code":"123 ","name":"Acteurs","professor":"LAlalalala","contentReview":"Très intéressant !","teachingReview":"Disponible, claire.","contentGrade":8,"teachingGrade":8,"average":8,"trimester":"T2","day":"Jeudi / Thursday","time":"9h-12h","round":"1er tour","bet":25,"year":"2014/2015","upvotes":"0","author":"Piranha","passed":null}]
```

I would like to add the elements found in the reviewsJson to the reviews field of the elements of coursesJson. Could that be the problem ? I thought that using the push() method would create the array, but maybe I need to change all "reviews":null to "reviews":[] in coursesJson ?

Comment: Could you post the jsons, I want to be able to see whats an array whats an object etc

Comment: You appear to be confusing things, `$scope.coursesJson` is an array yet your trying to access the property `name` directly off it. Shouldnt that be `$scope.coursesJson[i].name`? Also if you set your headers properly, `content-type` and `accepts` angular will parse the response for you. Finally your overwriting `coursesJson` with multiple different values, first there promises, then there arrays. You should avoid this practice.

Comment: `values` is array of promise objects created by `$http`. No need to use `fromJson()` either.

Comment: @charlietfl afraid not, values is an array of the resolved value from each promise, so in this case the response from `$http`.

Comment: @ste2425 which returns an object that includes the server response in `data` property

Comment: @charlietfl yes which is not a promise as you stated, but the value resolved by the `$http` promise.

Comment: @ste2425 fine...terminology aside the point is OP is expecting something else

Comment: hi, I heard your comment and changed everything you said. I am posting an example of the jsons in my initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue really easyly and my question was actually pretty stupid.

What I tried to achieve didn't have its place on the front but on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the url https://api.myjson.com/bins/ID1 and it's not an array, but an object. Instead of $scope.coursesJson.length  I think you shouldbe doing $scope.coursesJson.tracks.length

Comment: Hi, url/ID1 is not the actual URL I'm using, I used ID1 to just differentiate the two URLS. I'm going to add an example of the jsons on my opening post